# Removing space after section heading after using baselineskip

Tags: spacing, sectioning, enumerate

Basically after setting a large `\baselineskip` there is now a huge space under my section heading:
source:

```
\documentclass[14pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,paperwidth=496pt, paperheight=588pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,array,collcell,stix}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{36pt}
\section*{Converting repeating decimals to fractions}
    \begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1.]
    \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{3}$ \\
        then $10x=3.\dot{3}$ \\
        $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$ \\
        $9x=3$ \\
        $9x=\frac{3}{9}$
    \item Express $0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ \\
        then $100x=12.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ \\
        $100x-10x=12.\dot{1}\dot{2}-0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ \\
        $90x=12$ \\
        $x=\frac{12}{90}$ \\
        $x=\frac{2}{15}$ 
\end{enumerate}}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), you can just insert a vertical skip as part of the `before` key. So, for example, try

```
\begin{enumerate}[.., before={\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}}]
```

The following uses [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) as well to set the `enumerate` using `\doublespacing` rather than using forced linebreaks `\\`:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\documentclass[14pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,paperwidth=496pt, paperheight=588pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}

\show\doublespacing
\section*{Converting repeating decimals to fractions}
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1., before={\doublespacing\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}}]
  \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction.

    Let $x=0.\dot{3}$

    then $10x=3.\dot{3}$

    $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$

    $9x=3$

    $9x=\frac{3}{9}$

  \item Express $0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ as a fraction.

    Let $x=0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$

    then $100x=12.\dot{1}\dot{2}$

    $100x-10x=12.\dot{1}\dot{2}-0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$

    $90x=12$

    $x=\frac{12}{90}$

    $x=\frac{2}{15}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hey werner, you are really helpful, is there any chance i could add you on skype or something, because it rather time consuming for me to post a whole thread every time i have a niggling problem. if not no worries, and thanks for your answer yet again :)

Comment: @user1448093: I am very rarely on Skype. However, with [your current (and growing) reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), you can [get quiet quick responses in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends). The group there are very friendly and helpful. I understand the labour of writing up a post only to get a seemingly quick *and* helpful answer... but that's the StackExchange model, unless you like to jump in the chat room occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `\setlength{\baselineskip}` to a more sensible value. Or, if you have good reasons to have this value for this particular enumerate environment, as it happens that `\baselineskip` just before the `\section*` is also modified, you can:

1. insert  `\setlength{…}` just after `\begin{enumerate}`
2. add just after the `\section*` command a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`, say. Actually you should rather use a `setstretch{3}` and, to restore the exact vertical spacing between the section title and the following text, you should use \vspace{`-2`\baselineskip}, but the result doesn't look very good, in my opinion. Since I suggest this (I used the `book` class, as `memoir` is not installed on my system):

```
\documentclass[14pt,extrafontsizes]{book}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,paperwidth=496pt, paperheight=588pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,array,collcell,stix}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{setspace, etoolbox}
%\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\section*{Converting repeating decimals to fractions}
\vspace{-1\baselineskip}

\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1.]\setstretch{3}%
    \item Express $0.\dot{3}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{3}$ \\
        then $10x=3.\dot{3}$ \\
        $10x-x=3.\dot{3}-0.\dot{3}$ \\
        $9x=3$ \\
        $9x=\frac{3}{9}$
    \item Express $0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ as a fraction. \\
        Let $x=0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ \\
        then $100x=12.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ \\
        $100x-10x=12.\dot{1}\dot{2}-0.\dot{1}\dot{2}$ \\
        $90x=12$ \\
        $x=\frac{12}{90}$ \\
        $x=\frac{2}{15}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks bernard, I will read through this and try to understand!